# HTML5 document outline

Tags: html, browser

I have a few questions related to the HTML5 document outline.

1. It appears that the document outline is currently only used by the browser internally (Edit: false, not even by the browser). Does the document outline have any functional use? It appears that it is only useful for the developer to double-verify the structure, or perhaps for search engines.
2. If I understand correctly, with HTML5 the document outline is determined by semantic *section* elements (section, article), instead of the header hierarchy (html4). How safe is it to rely on this? What happens when a browser doesn't support the semantic tags?

So what is the actual added value of the document outline for the web developer / user?

Answer (score 0):

In [Mozilla developer's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document), it is given that

> There are currently no known implementations of the outline algorithm
>   in graphical browsers or assistive technology user agents, although
>   the algorithm is implemented in other software such as conformance
>   checkers. Therefore the outline algorithm cannot be relied upon to
>   convey document structure to users. Authors are advised to use heading
>   rank (h1-h6) to convey document structure.